# Xcode - cellForRowAtIndexpath - initialising cell

Tags: xcode, uitableview

What's the difference between this:

```
var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

And this:

```
var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
```

They both seem t work fine for me.

**PS:** I know this seems to be an amateur question but i'm beginner in Xcode, so no reason to be a smug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write :

```
var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

You are initializing a new cell using its constructor.

And when you write :

```
var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
```

You are dequeuing a cell, so you are assuming your cell with the identifier `cell` has been already registered in the `tableView`.

Typically, if the cell was designed in `Interface Builder` and set as a prototype cell or if you have registered your cell for reuse using the method `self.tableView.registerClass(MyCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")` you won't need to use the constructor because it is already initialized in the `tableView`.

But if your cell is designed programmatically such as creating `UILabel`, `UIImage` or whatever components, you **will** have to use the constructor instead, and then use the dequeue method.

So, if you have to use the constructor (because you're initializing everything by code) your code will look like this :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if cell == nil {
       cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    cell.cellLabel.text = "Hello world"
    cell.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "funny_cat.jpg")

    return cell
}
```

But if your cell was registered for reuse or if it is a prototype cell you will just have to use

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.cellLabel.text = "Hello world"
    cell.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "funny_cat.jpg")

    return cell
}
```

I think the best place to look how tableview work, you should look the official documentation here : [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

Comment: got it, but isn't it easier to customise your cell in storyboard instead of writing everything?

Comment: yes it is but sometimes you just have no choices... once again take a look at the official documentation you will have all informations you need